Cannot use variables in config.env file
I am beginner and learning backend.My config.env file is in the same folder.
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const dotenv = require('dotenv');
 const app = require('./app');

 dotenv.config();

 console.log(process.env.USERNAME);
 console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);


 console.log(process.env.DATABASE);
 const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
 '<PASSWORD>',
 process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
 );

mongoose
 .connect(DB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
 })
.then(() => {
  console.log(DB.connections);
  console.log('DATABASE CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY :)');
 });

// STARTING SERVER
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('Server is listening on port 3000!!');
});

My config.env file:
  NODE_ENV=development
 PORT=3000
 MINE_USERNAME=mufazzal
 PASSWORD=123456
 DATABASE=mongodb+srv://mufazzala16:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.zcxfqhq.mongodb.net/? 
 retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
 DATABASE_PASSWORD=Gujjar7434

i tried by adding path also and checked using console.log statements it says undefined. I am using HP laptop when i console.log(USERNAME) it says hp but i didnt specify hp in config.env

You should immediately change your password. You disclosed your password, I just connected successfully to your Mongo database!

I named my config.env file back to .env and it solved my problem.
